# When to use haram and halal-haram tags?

Tags: discussion, tag

I saw this question that contains [haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haram) tag which I replaced with [halal-haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-haram)

[Is it haram to hang up a picture of Manchester City badge?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/13082/is-it-haram-to-hang-up-a-picture-of-manchester-city-badge)

Why do we have two tags?

Should we keep them ?

Answer (score 2):

This is what I propose. Seems logical.

[halal-haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-haram): shall be used for questions which are asking whether the stated is halal or haram.

[halal](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal) and [haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haram): shall be used in questions where the person knows that the stated is halal/haram, and want to know the reason of and/or the source of that rule/law.

Comment: This seems to be a good line of division.  Is there really a reason to keep "halal" and "haram" separate though, or should they both be slaved to some sort of "explain-this-rule" sorta tag?

Comment: I can't foresee any utility of keeping them separate per se. I'm up for making it slaves to "explain-this-rule" kinda tag. "reason-for" or "reason" seems good.

Comment: Now that I think of it, that might be a good use for "[tag:islamic-rules]" which is also rather ambiguous.

Comment: Frankly I almost randomly choose between "islamic-rules" and "islamic-law" can't see their difference as such.