# How should we tidy up the halal/haram family of tags?

Tags: discussion, tag

When someone asks an "is X halal?" question, it is tagged with some almost-random subset of the following thirteen tags:

[halal](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal) (<strike>99 questions</strike> 1), [haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haram) (<strike>191</strike> 0), [halal-haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-haram) (609), [haram-halal](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haram-halal) (<strike>18</strike> 0), [halal-consumer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-consumer) (<strike>22</strike> 0), [sin](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sin) (99), [sin-or-not](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sin-or-not) (<strike>68</strike> 0), [permissible](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/permissible) (<strike>12</strike> <strike>10</strike> <strike>7</strike> <strike>4</strike> <strike>2</strike> 0), [forbidden](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forbidden) (<strike>7</strike> <strike>3</strike> 0), [lawful](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lawful) (<strike>four</strike> 0), [sharia](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharia) (919), [fiqh](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fiqh) (143), [islamic-ruling](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islamic-ruling) (<strike>89</strike> 0)

It's a mess!  (And, yeah... I confess I'm guilty of contributing to this mess, in my questions and through retagging.)

**Question**: How should we tidy up the halal/haram family of tags?

Some obvious steps would be:

- Synonymize: Map the tag [haram-halal](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haram-halal) to [halal-haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-haram) (it's hard to tell they're even different!).  It's already been suggested as a synonym: [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tags/halal-haram/synonyms).
- Manually retagging the three [forbidden](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forbidden) questions: <strike>[1](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/33571/17163) [2](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/11331/17163) [3](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/7601/17163)</strike>. Done.
- Manually phase out the ten [permissible](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/permissible) questions: <strike>[1](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/35852/17163) [2](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/33616/17163) [3](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/31037/17163)</strike> <strike>[4](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/29883/17163) [5](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/27859/17163) [6](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/25452/17163)</strike> <strike>[7](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/24887/17163) [8](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/17952/17163)</strike> <strike>[9](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/17942/17163) [10](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/5637/17163)</strike>. Done.
- Manually phase out the [lawful](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lawful) tags.  Done.

As for the less obvious...

If we generate a [tag graph](https://github.com/stared/tag-graph-map-of-stackexchange/wiki) for the site, we can plot it as:

[image: Gephi tag graph]

[image: Gephi tag graph 2]

(Click to enlarge.)

Nodes in these graphs are tags, and if two tags are closer together, they will tend to be more closely related.  (I use two different algorithms.)  What we see:

- There's barely any distinction between [halal-haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-haram), [halal](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal), [haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haram), [halal-consumer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-consumer).  And given that 'halal' and 'haram' are antonyms, anything pertaining to 'halal' also pertains to 'haram', and vice versa.  This suggests replacing the [halal](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal) and [haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haram) tags with [halal-haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-haram).

  - 41 questions have both tags [halal](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal) and [haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haram), and four of those also have the [halal-haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-haram).

  It might also be worth replacing [halal-consumer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-consumer) with [halal-haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-haram) together with other tags such as [food](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food) and [medical](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medical).  But looking through these questions, I think it'd be better to do this manually (if at all).
- There's strong distinctions between [halal-haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-haram) and [sharia](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharia) and [fiqh](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fiqh).
- The [sin-or-not](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sin-or-not) tag is virtually useless:

  [image: sin-or-not tag]

  and 14 questions (out of 68) are co-tagged either [halal-haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-haram) (8), [halal](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal) (1), [haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haram) (1), or [sin](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sin) (4).
- The [sin](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sin) tag isn't much better:

  [image: sin tag]

  with 9 questions (out of 99) co-tagged either [halal-haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-haram) (5) and [haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haram) (4).

  NB. [sin](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sin) has been proposed as a synonym of [sin-or-not](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sin-or-not), [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tags/sin-or-not/synonyms).

  As far as I know 'sin' is equivalent in meaning to 'haram action' (or inaction).  So it might be worth considering mapping both [sin](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sin) and [sin-or-not](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sin-or-not) to [halal-haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-haram) too (after careful consideration, of course).
- There's little distinction between the [fiqh](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fiqh) and [islamic-ruling](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islamic-ruling) tags.

  [image: fiqh and islamic-ruling tags]

  I noticed [islamic-ruling](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islamic-ruling) is proposed as tag synonym for [sharia](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharia), but the graph suggests it would be better for it to be a synonym of [fiqh](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fiqh).  The closeness arises due by the connections [islamic-ruling](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islamic-ruling) to [fatwa](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fatwa) to [fiqh](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fiqh), which aren't present between [islamic-ruling](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islamic-ruling) and [sharia](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharia).  (NB. A previous tag [islamic-rules](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islamic-rules) was synonymized with [sharia](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharia).)

---

This issue was raised before, [When to use haram and halal-haram tags?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1126/17163), where [Bleeding Fingers♦](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1127/17163) proposed:

> [halal-haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-haram): shall be used for questions which are asking
>   whether the stated is halal or haram.
>
> [halal](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal) and [haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haram): shall be used in questions where the
>   person knows that the stated is halal/haram, and want to know the
>   reason of and/or the source of that rule/law.

I'm going to (respectfully) disagree with this.  The problem I see is that it's unintuitive, so new users will learn to do this through trial-and-error.  (I had no idea when I first joined.)  It seems simpler just to have 'halal-haram' pop up as the tag suggestion whenever 'halal' or 'haram' is inputted.

Comment: The tag chaos isn't something new, but your graphs are really great, helpful and explanative.

Comment: I thought it was chaos too... but looking carefully through the graphs has changed my mind.  Aside from this halal/haram mess, I found a bunch of quibbles that I think could be improved [my next meta post (inshallah)].  Overall, despite trying to find problematic tags, I found very little.

Comment: Wow, this has been mentioned three times before: [Synonyms and Merges](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/321), [List of tag synonyms and tags to be burninated or removed](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/149), and [Removing some tags](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/72).

Answer (score 2):

I edited away the [haram-halal](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haram-halal) tag.  I don't think it will be missed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Note that at the moment I'm not able to look at your chart due to a firewall, but basically I'd say IMHO [halal](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal), [haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haram) , [halal-haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-haram) , [haram-halal](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haram-halal) , [halal-consumer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-consumer) should be summarized in one tag 
 either [halal-haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-haram) or [haram-halal](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haram-halal).
If we want to keep one of them, I'd prefer the first, as things are in first place halal as long as there's no evidence for the opposite!

This is because anything which isn't halal is automatically haram and vice versa this way one tag could resolve the issue and in case of doubt it is always good to use the halal-haram tag!

Now on the other hand shari'a says what is halal or haram, fiqh is the applied science for shari'a so maybe a distinction could be made between them, but is this the best solution?. Note that we also have a tag [usol-al-fiqh](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usol-al-fiqh) which only applies for the sources each madhab or sect builds her interpretation of shari'a on.
This is by definition a distinct tag.

Also a sin is something haram.

IMO **adjectives** such as [lawful](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lawful), [permissible](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/permissible), [forbidden](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forbidden) etc. **shouldn't be tags at al**l... I'm aware that this answer is no more actual, but I think this is an important point... ok strictly speaking halal حلال and haram حرام are adjectives but they have nouns in Arabic al-halal الحلال and al-haram الحرام ;).

So maybe a better, but maybe hard to establish choice is to summarize all the halal/haram tags in the fiqh tag because fiqh gives a qualification of what is halal or haram and is a noun.

Then one could discuss whether a tag shari'a is necssary.

Answer (score 1):

I edited away the [halal-consumer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-consumer) tag.

[image]

There's a [halal-certification](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-certification) tag now.

It may still be worthwhile creating a tag like [consumption](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/consumption), [buying](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/buying), or [shopping](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shopping) when discussing purchasing things.  But most of the formerly tagged [halal-consumer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-consumer) questions were "Is X halal?" when someone was considering buying something.

Answer (score 1):

I edited away the [sin-or-not](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sin-or-not) tag.  I encountered nothing I felt concerned about doing this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I edited away the [islamic-ruling](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islamic-ruling) tag.  I mostly found "Is X halal?" questions phrased as "What is the Islamic ruling on X?"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I edited away the [halal](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal) tag.  It was mostly used as "Is X halal?" (where [halal-haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-haram) can be used), with a handful of [halal-certification](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-certification) questions thrown in.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I edited away the [haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haram) tag.  We can use [halal-haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-haram) instead.

[image]