# How do the other religion SE sites tag "Is X halal?" questions?

Tags: discussion, tag

Thinking about [Let's not have an "Is X halal?" tag?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2944/17163), it would be a good idea to see how the other religion StackExchange sites handle "Is X halal?" questions.

**Thoughts**:

1. Judaism.SE has a similar problem to the [halal/haram mess](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1844/how-should-we-tidy-up-the-halal-haram-family-of-tags), but to a lesser extent.  It is partly language related.  They seem to have funnelled these questions into the tags "halacha" (= Jewish law) and "sin".  The tag "halacha" is bloated, and 28% of all questions use this tag.

   For the other religion SE sites, it's more natural to think to use the "sin" tag, so it's less of a problem.
2. No other site has so many potential tags that could be used to mean "Is X halal?".
3. At each site there are questions which ask "Is X halal?", but do not have an "Is X halal?" tag.
4. There seems to be questions about "sin" which are not of the form "Is X halal?"  This suggests:

   - There might be some value in retaining the [sin](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sin) tag here (if the tags [sharia](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharia) or [fiqh](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fiqh) don't work), but removing the "Is X halal?" questions from it; and
   - The tag [sin-or-not](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sin-or-not) should *not* be made a synonym of [sin](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sin), but deleted from questions, thus making it a possible target for a StackExchange burninate request.

---

## Judaism.SE

We have the tags:

- "**[halacha](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halacha)**" (= Jewish law)

  It's the most common tag on Judaism.SE by a *huge* margin; with 28% of all questions using this tag; (6206 questions vs. 1311 for the next-most-popular tag).  [We're at 13% with [sharia](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharia).]  There's a meta post, [The halacha-jewish-law tag](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/121/14224), where a range of solutions were considered, but none seem to be implemented.

  Example questions:

  1. [Is it forbidden for a woman to learn Gemara?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7071/14224)

     - Tags: "[halacha](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halacha)" "[talmud-gemara](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/talmud-gemara)" "[women](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/women)" "[torah-study](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/torah-study)"
  2. [Is there any issue with using aerosols on Shabbos?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12605/14224)

     - Tags: "[halacha](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halacha)" "[shabbat](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shabbat)" "[technology](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technology)" "[melacha-creative-work](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/melacha-creative-work)"
- "**[sin](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sin)**" (synonyms: "transgressions" and "averah")

  Example questions:

  1. [Is studying Greek culture a sin?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/78680/14224)

     - Tags: "[chanuka](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chanuka)" "[sin](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sin)" "[chabad](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chabad)" "[chassidic-rebbe](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chassidic-rebbe)" "[secular-culture](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/secular-culture)"
  2. [Is it a sin to joke about sinning?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/67656/14224)

     - Tags: "[halacha](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halacha)" "[sin](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sin)" "[humor](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/humor)" "[joke](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/joke)"

Example questions which don't use an "Is X halal?" tag:

1. [Is it forbidden to try to give a specific description of HaShem?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/62313/14224)

   - Tags: "[hashkafah-philosophy](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hashkafah-philosophy)" "[theology](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theology)"
2. [Is it forbidden to urinate in front of someone?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/60106/14224)

   - Tag: "[bathroom](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bathroom)"

There's also the "[kashrut-kosher](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kashrut-kosher)" tag (= Jewish dietary laws; synonyms "kashrut", "kashrus" and "kosher") but it doesn't seem to apply in the "Is X halal?" setting.

## Christianity.SE

*Note*: Questions of the form "Is X halal?" are [declared off topic](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1486/what-to-do-with-is-x-a-sin-questions) as [Truth questions](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3527/we-cant-handle-the-truth) unless they restrict to a specific denomination.

We have the tag:

- "**[sin](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sin)**"

  45% of questions tagged "sin" are closed.  Most of these questions don't have the format "Is X halal?"

  Example questions:

  1. [According to Catholicism, is it sinful to drink alcohol in order to get drunk?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/53334/9617)

     - Tags: "[catholicism](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/catholicism)" "[sin](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sin)" "[christian-living](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/christian-living)" "[alcohol](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alcohol)"
  2. [Does Catholicism consider bisexuality and asexuality sinful?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/50153/9617)

     - Tags: "[catholicism](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/catholicism)" "[sin](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sin)" "[sexuality](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sexuality)" "[homosexuality](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homosexuality)"

Example questions which don't use an "Is X halal?" tag:

1. [According to the Bible, is it a sin to marry a non-virgin?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/9315/9617)

   - Tags: "[marriage](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marriage)" "[sexuality](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sexuality)"
2. [Is it a sin or forbidden to follow any of the parts of the Law of Moses?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/11579/9617)

   - Tags: "[biblical-basis](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biblical-basis)" "[old-testament](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/old-testament)" "[mosaic-law](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mosaic-law)" "[capital-punishment](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/capital-punishment)"

## Hinduism.SE

We have the tag:

- "**[papam](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/papam)**" (synonym: "sin")

  Example questions:

  1. [Is taking interest from bank a sin?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16278)

     - Tags: "[belief](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/belief)" "[bhagavad-gita](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bhagavad-gita)" "[karma](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/karma)" "[papam](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/papam)" "[scripture](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripture)"
  2. [Is bribery a sin according to Hindu scripture? If yes, what is the punishment?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15090)

     - Tags: "[mahabharata](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mahabharata)" "[scripture](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripture)" "[ramayana](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ramayana)" "[papam](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/papam)"

Example questions which don't use an "Is X halal?" tag:

1. [Is bathing without cloth a sin?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/12169)

   - Tags: "[rituals](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rituals)"
2. [Is cutting vegetables sin according to Sanatana dharma?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3903)

   - Tags: "[practice](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/practice)" "[dharma](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dharma)" "[prayer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prayer)" "[non-vegetarian](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/non-vegetarian)"

---

**Buddhism.SE** doesn't seem to have well-developed tags in this matter, e.g.:

1. [Is homosexuality a sin?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/14154)

   - Tags: "[sexuality](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sexuality)" "[sexual-misconduct](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sexual-misconduct)"
2. [Is ignorance a sin?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/12819/is-ignorance-a-sin)

   - Tags: "[karma](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/karma)"

Thus, I won't include this site for precedent.