# Plan of attack for tidying the halal/haram family of tags

Tags: discussion, tag

While [I'm not sure if we even need an "Is X halal?" tag](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2944/17163), I'm confident that the number of tags with this meaning should be either 0 or 1.

***Underlying goal***:

- Make the [halal-haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-haram) tag the only "Is X halal?" tag.

***Plan of attack***:

- Stage 1 (**Done.**):

  - Edit away [halal-consumer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-consumer) one by one.  (**Done.**)
  - Edit away [sin-or-not](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sin-or-not) one by one.  (**Done.**)
  - Edit away [islamic-ruling](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islamic-ruling) one by one.  (**Done.**)
- Stage 2 (**Done.**):  I aim to reduce the number of questions with [halal](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal), [haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haram), and [sin](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sin) tags to check in Stage 3.  These questions are usually poorly tagged, so it makes sense to do them first:

  - Retag questions tagged both [halal-haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-haram) and [halal](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal); [search](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal+halal-haram).  (**Done.**)
  - Retag questions tagged both [halal-haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-haram) and [haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haram); [search](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haram+halal-haram).  (**Done.**)
  - Retag questions tagged both [halal-haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-haram) and [sin](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sin); [search](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sin+halal-haram).  (**Done.**)  Turns out, there seems to be a few questions that seem to need both tags.
  - Retag questions tagged both [halal](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal) and [haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haram); [search](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal+haram).  (**Done.**)
- Stage 3 (*In progress.*):  For questions that ask "Is X halal?", change it to [halal-haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-haram).

  - Go through the [halal](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal) (41 Q's) questions one by one.  (**Done.**)  I didn't find any reason this tag is specifically needed.  They either worked without the tag entirely, or could be adequately retagged [halal-haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-haram), [halal-certification](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-certification), or [sin](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sin).
  - Go through the [haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haram) (143 Q's) questions one by one.  (**Done.**)  I get the impression the [haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haram) tag is not needed.  (*Update*: it's gone.)
  - Go through the [sin](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sin) (112 Q's) questions one by one.  (**Done.**)
- Stage 4 (**Done.**):  Identify how the tags [halal](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal), [haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haram), and [sin](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sin) are used.  Discuss on meta, ideally providing guidelines and updating the tag wiki excerpts.  Here: [How to decide which halal/haram tag(s) to use](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3113/17163)
- Stage 5 (*In progress.*):  Go through the [halal-haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-haram) (920 Q's) questions one by one, and identify and retag those where it's *not* used as an "Is X halal?" tag.
- Stage 6 (*Not yet started.*):  Move onto the [sharia](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharia) and [fiqh](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fiqh) tags.  I don't have a current plan of attack here.  See also: [Which questions should be tagged "sharia" and/or "fiqh"?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3141/17163)

---

I asked about it [here](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1844/17163), and I get the impression we're mostly (if not all) on board about tidying up this mess.

***How to help?***  For questions on the front page which ask "Is X halal?", please tag them [halal-haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-haram) and the tag(s) relating to X.  *The [halal-haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-haram) tag should not be the only tag.*

---

Justifications:

- My impression is that [sin-or-not](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sin-or-not) (46 Q's) and [halal-consumer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-consumer) (9 Q's) are used predominately as "Is X halal?" tags.  There were some exceptions for "halal certification" questions; these can be tagged more clearly by the new [halal-certification](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-certification) tag.
- In my opinion, [islamic-ruling](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islamic-ruling) (70 Q's) is a poorly used tag; questions can be about virtually anything and get this tag arbitrarily.
- I'm fairly sure the tags [halal](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal) (80 Q's) and [haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haram) (175 Q's) are primarily used as an "Is X halal?" tag.  My current expectation is that we won't need these tags in addition to [halal-haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-haram).
- I've changed my mind about getting rid of the [sin](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sin) (108 Q's) tag.  It works for questions about sins in general.  However, some questions use it as an "Is X halal?" tag.
- I've previously edited away [haram-halal](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haram-halal), [permissible](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/permissible), [forbidden](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forbidden), [lawful](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lawful).  No one has complained (yet).