# How to decide which halal/haram tag(s) to use

Tags: discussion, tag

**Summary**:  This has become my algorithm for (re)tagging halal/haram-related questions:

1. For questions about the haram-ness of X, use [halal-haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-haram) (and the tags for X).
2. For questions about sins in general, use [sin](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sin).
3. For questions about halal certification, use [halal-certification](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-certification).
4. For questions about X, but not about its haram-ness, just use the tags for X.

---

Long version.  The following has become my algorithm for (re)tagging questions in an effort to tidy up the [halal/haram family of tags](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1844/how-should-we-tidy-up-the-halal-haram-family-of-tags).  I tried to make it [*as simple as possible, but not simpler*](http://quoteinvestigator.com/2011/05/13/einstein-simple/).

### 1. The haram-ness of X.

Use [halal-haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-haram) when the question is about the haram-ness of X.  *Please also use the appropriate tags for X.*

**Examples**:

1. *Is X haram?*  (etc.)

   - [Is it permissible to photograph nature?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/38088/17163) is tagged [halal-haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-haram) and [photos](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photos).
2. *How haram is X?*  (etc.)

   - [How important is eating halal meat?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/2979/17163) is tagged [halal-haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-haram), [food](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food), and [meat](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meat).
3. *Under what conditions is X haram?*  (etc.)

   - [Is suicide allowed in any circumstances?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36717/17163) is tagged [halal-haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-haram) and [suicide](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suicide).
4. *Why is X haram?*  (etc.)

   - [Why isn't caffeine haraam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40695/17163) is tagged [halal-haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-haram) and [food](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food).

Many synonyms and antonyms for "haram" may be used in phrasing a question about the haram-ness of X (sinful, forbidden, unlawful; halal, permissible, allowed, lawful; etc.).

### 2. Sins in general.

Use [sin](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sin) for questions about sins in general.

1. [Will Allah forgive us for a sin that we commit knowing that it is haram?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/12186/17163) is tagged [sin](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sin), [tawba](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tawba), and [forgiveness](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forgiveness).
2. [Is it okay if we commit a sin with a clean intention?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/25070/17163) is tagged [halal-haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-haram), [sin](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sin), and [hadith-interpretation](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hadith-interpretation).

This last one is an example of where we might use both the [halal-haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-haram) and [sin](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sin) tags.

### 3. Halal certification.

Use [halal-certification](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-certification) for questions about halal certification.  (Consider adding [food](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food) or [meat](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meat) too.)

1. [Are there any special rules about the halal certification of dairy foods?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/18477/17163) is tagged [halal-certification](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-certification) and [food](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food).

### 4. Questions about X, but not about its haram-ness.

Just use the appropriate tags for X.

1. [How to avoid zina?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/2322/17163) is tagged [practical-islam](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/practical-islam) and [zina](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zina).

---

Comments...

- There's a lot of questions; most are not yet retagged to match the above.  This will take time.
- The usage of [sin](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sin) as per the above would be clearer if this tag were renamed [sins](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sins).
- I haven't figured out what to do with the [sharia](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharia), [fiqh](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fiqh), and [usool-ul-fiqh](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usool-ul-fiqh) tags yet.  However, many of these questions should be retagged [halal-haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-haram), and after that it would be clearer.
- I intend to edit away the [haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haram) tag too.  (The [halal](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal) tag ended up edited away.)  After this is done:

  1. when you type "halal" into the tag box, it gives the suggestions: [halal-haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-haram) and [halal-certification](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-certification)
  2. when you type "haram" into the tag box, it gives the suggestions: [halal-haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-haram) and some obviously unrelated tags: [muharram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/muharram) and [masjid-al-haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/masjid-al-haram)
  3. when you type "sin" into the tag box, it gives the suggestions: [sin](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sin) and some obviously unrelated tags: [business](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/business), etc.

  I'm hoping this will lead people to select the [halal-haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-haram) themselves.
- I edited the tag wiki excerpt for [halal-haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-haram):

  > Questions about determining permissibility: "Is X haram/sinful/forbidden?", "How haram is X?", "Under what conditions is X haram?". (Do not use this tag by itself; add the relevant tags for X.)

  I'm not sure if this is the best wording.  Maybe this can be improved over time.

Comment: If this were Meta Stack Overflow, someone would have made the title have a pun such as "This tag is [haram]". https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295583/why-do-people-have-a-little-pun-with-their-retag-and-burninate-requests

Comment: Ah, a wasted opportunity... (: